# Нужна запятая перед КАК?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Друг — это тот, кто всегда поинтересуется как у тебя дела?

Comment: Вот только в конце предложения не восклицательный знак, а точка. Вы же утверждаете, а не спрашиваете, предложение повествовательное. Вопросительное было бы в предложении с прямой речью: 
Друг — это тот, кто всегда поинтересуется: "Как у тебя дела?"

Answer (score 3):

Друг — это тот, кто всегда поинтересуется, **как у тебя дела.**

Запятая ставится **перед придаточной изъяснительной частью предложения**, КАК — союзное слово, "поинтересуется" — опорный глагол со значением речи.

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с двумя придаточными с последовательной связью: 1) местоименно-определительное, 2) изъяснительное.

Comment: Вопросительный знак сознательно оставлен или просто скопирован из текста вопроса?

Comment: Скопирован. Вообще говоря, вопросительный знак после изъяснительного придаточного ставится, но только  в качестве авторского знака.